# How can I create two node types from one csv in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, many-to-many

I only have this csv:

### nameaddress.csv

[image]

and I want to create this network in neo4j =
[image]

How I can do this easily ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'csvFilePath' as row MERGE(people: People {name:row.name}) MERGE(address:Address {name:row.address})
MERGE (people)-[r:WENT_TO]->(address) RETURN people,address;